# Beginners question - Why does C use * to declare a pointer and not &?

Tags: c, cs50

So let's say:

```
int n = 50;
int *p = &n;
```

Why do we use `*` and not `&` in C? What's the key difference between `*` and `&`?

Comment: A “\*” is used to denote a pointer type because that is the *syntax*. No other reason need exist. The unary \* operator (which is _different_ from a type declaration, regardless of using the same symbol) is a pointer-dereference and the & unary operator is address-of.

Comment: What do you mean "why"? Because the language syntax is like that, that's why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `*` to declare pointers is mostly a matter of convention, but there is a reason of consistency: the `*` in the declaration `int *p` means *`int` is the type of `*p`*.

It might seem more consistent to write `int &p = &n` as `p` is initialized to the address of `n` but this convention would not hold for double pointers: `int **pp` defines `pp` as a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, yet `pp` cannot be initialized with `&(&n)`.

Note that `int& p = n;` is a valid definition in C++ for a reference to an `int`, which is a pointer in disguise. Modifying `p` would then modify `n`. References are implemented as pointers without the indirection notation.

Comment: The declaration of `p` you've shown (`int *p`) means `p is a pointer-to-int`, I'd read it as "int pointer p", and the `*` in `int *p` means 'pointer', at least to me. YMMV.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica: interesting remark. I don't usually read code aloud, and I would probably read *int star p*, or when teaching French programmers *int étoile p*. Your vocalisation is more sensible and less confusing. How would you pronounce `char *argv[]`?

Comment: I'd pronounce that as "char (pronounced 'care' - my code doesn't smolder :-) pointer array argv", or maybe as "array of char pointers argv".

Answer (score 2):

C declarations follow a convention often described as “declaration mimics use”.  The structure of a declaration matches (as closely as possible) the structure of an expression in the code.

For example, let’s say you have a pointer to an `int` named `p`.  To access the value stored in the pointed-to object, we *dereference* the pointer with the unary `*` operator, like so:

```
printf( "value of what p points to is %d\n", *p );
```

The *expression* `*p` has type `int`, so we declare `p` as

```
int *p;
```

This conveys that the variable `p` has type "pointer to `int`", because the *combination* of `p` and the dereference operator `*` in the declarator yield an expression of type `int`.

And this is primarily why pointers aren't declared using the `&` operator in C, because the type of the *expression* `&p` wouldn't be `int`.

C++ uses the unary `&` operator to declare *references*, which are not the same thing as pointers:

```
void foo( int &ref )
{
  ref = new_value(); // writes a new value to the actual parameter ref references
}

int main( void )
{
  int x = 1;
  std::cout << "x before foo = " << x << std::endl;
  foo( x );
  std::cout << "x after foo = " << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

References kind of break this system - there's no `&ref` *expression* that has type `int`, it just notes that `ref` resolves to the same object as some other identifier.

---

C declarations are made up of two parts - a sequence of *declaration specifiers* (storage class specifier, type qualifier(s), type specifier(s)) followed by a sequence of (possibly initialized) *declarators*.  Pointer-ness, array-ness, and function-ness are specified in the declarator:

```
            declaration specifiers           declarators
                     |                           |
+--------------------+----------------+ +--------+--------+
|                                     | |                 |
static const volatile unsigned long int a[10], *p, f(void);
   |   |            | |               | |      |   |
   |   |            | |               | |      |   +––––––– function declarator
   |   |            | |               | |      +––––––––––– pointer declarator
   |   |            | |               | +––––––––—–––––——–– array declarator
   |   |            | +–––––––+––––––—+
   |   |            |         |
   |   |            |         +––––––––––––––——–––––––––––— type specifiers
   |   +––––––+–––––+
   |          |
   |          +–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– type qualifiers
   +–––––––––––––—––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– storage class specifier
```

This is important - there's no "pointer to" type specifier.  The pointerness is specified by the declarator.  If you write something like

```
int* a, b;
```

it will be parsed as

```
int (*a), b;
```

and only `a` will be declared as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In C `*` in a variable definition means "pointer to". In an expression the `&` operator means "address of", while `*` operator means "dereference".

So in effect:

```
int n = 1;
int* p = &n; // Create a pointer and initialize with the address of n

if (*p == 1) {
  // This is true when dereferencing the pointer
}
```

Why not use `&` as in `int& p`? Mostly because the syntax isn't set up that way.

It's worth noting that in C++ the `&` comes back to mean "reference":

```
int n = 1;
int& r = n;
```

Note there's no need for any special treatment on the right-hand side, it just figures it out.

Comment: Thank you! So this is the matter of syntax and convention? I’m learning so I want to make sure...

Comment: It's how C was defined by the [creators of C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language).